# Angular loop over scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops

How can I loop over `$scope.properties` object values and put them into separate `$scope.coords` list in `Angular`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var propertyModule = angular.module(
        'propertyModule', 
        ['ngResource', 'ngMap', 'ngRoute']
    );
    propertyModule.controller(
        'propertyController', 
        [
            '$scope', 
            'Property', 
            function ($scope, Property) {
                // Query returns an array of objects, MyModel.objects.all() by default
                $scope.properties = Property.query();
                // Getting a single object
                $scope.property = Property.get({pk: 1});
                $scope.coords = [];
            }
        ]
    );
</script>
```

`$scope.properties` returns a json with:

```
[
    {
        "city":1,
        "name":"Pastatas A",
        "coordinates":[24.43359375,54.6611237221],"pk":1
    },
    {
        "city":1,
        "name":"hmgbjmnbm",
        "coordinates":[25.2905273438,54.6738309659],
        "pk":4
    },
    {
        "city":1,
        "name":"gfghfghfg",
        "coordinates":[25.3344726562,54.6102549816],
        "pk":3
    },
    {
        "city":1,
        "name":"sdfsdgsdgsdgasssss",
        "coordinates":[25.2685546875,54.6801830971],
        "pk":5
    },
    {
        "city":2,
        "name":"Test flat",
        "coordinates":[25.2960205078,54.6611237221],
        "pk":6
    }
]
```

I want `$scope.coords` to contain only coordinate values. It is necessary that `$scope.coords` would be in the controller.

Comment: Hello. Thanks, but unfortunately my template shows `[null,null]`, and console.log() tells me:

`[undefined, undefined]`
`[undefined, undefined]`

Maybe its because I am trying to iterate over query ?..

Comment: @Jack Allen: Please don't go around changing code to your preferred code style. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/660921

Comment: @Carpetsmoker have you read what you posted? fortunately my changes follow these rules, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/xudan/1/edit

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){

      $scope.properties  = [
        {
            "city":1,
            "name":"Pastatas A",
            "coordinates":[24.43359375,54.6611237221],"pk":1
        },{
            "city":1,
            "name":"hmgbjmnbm",
            "coordinates":[25.2905273438,54.6738309659],
            "pk":4
        },{
            "city":1,
            "name":"gfghfghfg",
            "coordinates":[25.3344726562,54.6102549816],
            "pk":3
        },{
            "city":1,
            "name":"sdfsdgsdgsdgasssss",
            "coordinates":[25.2685546875,54.6801830971],
            "pk":5
        },{
            "city":2,
            "name":"Test flat",
            "coordinates":[25.2960205078,54.6611237221],
            "pk":6
        }
    ];
      $scope.coords  = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.properties , function(value){

        $scope.coords.push(value.coordinates);

      });
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me an empty array of []... Maybe the reason is because I am trying to iterate over $scope.properties = Property.query(); ? It is querying my Django Model and returning a JSON in the runtime..

Comment: that happened because you iterate by $scope.properties before you get data please try this http://jsbin.com/xudan/2/edit

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I am iterating over $scope.properties after I get data, the code still does not work for some reason. I am getting nothing in my template.

Comment: please see here http://jsbin.com/xudan/3/edit  and let me know what your console shows

Comment: Console shows:

`[Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, $promise: Object, $resolved: true]
 ` I guess that the json thing doesnt get instantiated, thats why I cant loop over it. It is just an object.

Comment: please see here http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic-crud-operations.html and try to add 'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true}, in Property service

Comment: I have updated my code, but am still getting the same results as mentioned before... Maybe I did something wrong ? The code: http://pastebin.com/2ePQbt9K

Comment: I am sorry for confusing you, I forgot to put `{% verbatim %}` Django tag to the last try, so your last line from Djangular docs helped me! It seems that the code works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$scope.coords = [];
for(var i=0;i<$scope.properties.length;i++){
    $scope.coords.push($scope.properties[i].coordinates);
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dAQs/) Check the console

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me an empty array of []... Maybe the reason is because I am trying to iterate over $scope.properties = Property.query(); ? It is querying my Django Model and returning a JSON in the runtime..

Comment: If it is an asynchronous thing then in your factory you need to implement promise and whenever you get data you then need to have this for loop

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you, I will try to do this.

Comment: The data is not asynchronous, it is just loaded by querying my django model and Json is returned. When I am pasting json data into $scope.properties, the code works. But when scope.properties = Property.query(), I cant loop over that json anynore. I can display it, but the loop doesnt work.

Comment: you can create a service in which you m=would inject $q service and then call the django database and get the data. On the data recieved you would resolve the promise. and over here in your controller you would then use .then. In order to wait for your database call to complete you can set $interval to check for data if it has come.